# Python replace plus sign from excel

Tags: python, csv

The data I pull from DB comes in the following format:

```
+jacket
online trading account
+neptune
```

When I write this data to a CSV I end up with a `#NAME?` error. I tried adding single quote `'` to the front of the values when I pull the data, however, this does not fix the issue. I need to write the values exactly as they come, with the plus sign at the front.

Comment: Make your question a bit clearer... What do you expect to get. Can you add an example?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I would like the output in excel to be as follows for values with a plus sign: `+jacket`

Comment: Please add clarification. Is the first line literally "+jacket"? Or something else?

Comment: For simplicity lets say all i have in the set is "+jacket". I would like to write this to csv and not get a #NAME? error in excel. I would like to see +jacket when i open up the excel.

Comment: '+jacket is the proper escaping method for excel. Pulling the data should not involve the quote, but adding the string to the excel document should use the quote. Do you have the code which shows your attempt to add the string to excel?

Comment: @JacobIRR I would write it in sql as follows: `case when LEFT(ak.KEYWORD, 1) = '+' then '''' ||  ak.KEYWORD  else ak.KEYWORD end AS Keyword` which write `'+jacket` but when I paste or write it to excel I still have this single quote, which I do not want.

Comment: Alternatively to escaping it, enclose it fully in quotes `"+jacket"` and when Excel opens this as a CSV file it will interpret the data as string/text. The quote marks will not be present in Excel.

Comment: @DavidZemens doesn't seem to be working when I tested it

Comment: hmmm. I just manually created a text file with a .csv extension and seemed to work for me, but without seeing your code like how you're actually creating the file, it's hard to say. It *should* work, at least based on my crude test, but if you show the code maybe I will see something that needs to be tweaked.

Comment: @DavidZemens I also manually created a file and enclosed the keyword in double quotes.

Comment: no spaces between fields in the csv?

Comment: show example screenshot or data from the csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to format the desired output column as a text column. This will result in:

```
+jacket
online trading account
+neptune
```

being written to the file exactly as is. No more #NAME? errors.

Comment: Genius! Thank you so much!